# Why does my AJAX post request not work correctly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

My AJAX method in Django does not seem to be working and I'm having trouble determining where it is broken because I'm not actually getting any errors in the Django debug log, it is returning a 200 status code.

Template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_app = {
      username: {{ request.user.username }}  
    };
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/accounts/" + my_app.username + "/profile_listview",
            data: { entryname:id },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.success);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Or maybe the error is in the actual jQuery AJAX portion?  Chrome dev console is giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: benjamin is not defined(index):223 (anonymous function)
```

I don't know what that means exactly, but the fact that it says benjamin, means the name is properly assigned.

```
VIEWS.PY

latest_entries=Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]

@login_required
def delete_object(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      print "ajax request detected"
      object_name = request.POST.get('entryname')
      Entry.objects.get(id=object_name).delete()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/storefront/')
```

Another thing I should mention is that I added the print "ajax request detected" to confirm if the method is even being called, but nothing prints to the terminal when i am testing this, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why are you trying to do a Redirect in your view if the AJAX is trying to show an alert?
Use quotes in the username value to make JavaScript to detect a value and not a variable.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm going to remove the alert.  All I want is the redirect.

Comment: If you only want the redirect you should return an HttpResponse with the URL that you want to redirect to, and make the redirect in the AJAX success call

Comment: Why can't I just do all of that from within the views?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your username in quotes:

```
var my_app = {
    username: '{{ request.user.username }}'
};
```

The `Benjamin is not defined` error is because JavaScript thinks you're referencing a variable of that name, instead of defining a string value.

Comment: Do you think that's also why "ajax request detected" in my view method is not printing?